# customize the Border property with CornerRadius for ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, border, cornerradius

I want to customize the following Listbox-display property of border with CornerRadius=5..can anyone help me to achieve it without changing the existing datatemplate code in the following Xaml code:

```
<ListBox x:Uid="lst_value"  Name="lstValues" Background="Wheat" BorderBrush="Black"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="1" Height="100" Width="150"
         ItemsSource="{Binding listval}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="{Binding}">
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtblk" Foreground="Black" FontSize="10"  TextAlignment="Left" 
                                               FontWeight="Black" Text="{Binding}" Background="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want the `Border` within the `ListBoxItems` to have another `CornerRadius` value, you can either re-template `ListBoxItem` where the `Border` is defined, or set it implicitly in the `ItemContainerStyle` Resources

```
<ListBox ...>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <!--...-->
</ListBox>
```

**Edit:** If you want to set `CornerRadius` for the `ListBox`, you can do the same but in `Resources` instead

```
    <ListBox ...>
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
    <!--...-->
</ListBox>
```

Comment: yes, we can have a border inside the listbox for every listItem...where as I need the border property with cornerradius to be applied for the entire Listbox itself....hope am clear with my question..

Comment: So you want to round the corners of the `ListBox` and have a `Border`, is that correct?

Comment: Updated my answer with how you can do this for the `ListBox` instead of the `ListBoxItems`

Comment: That was perfect... but then the items in the listbox once selected were no longer having the background color(it is just white background for the selected items) and other than that I doesn't have the default listbox behaviour(i.e., single selection and multiple selection for the items). Instead, they were highlighted or selected irrespectively....Am a completely new for WPF...it would be more helpful for me...if you could guide me the way out to resolve it..Thank you..