# rounded corners on a ListBox

Tags: wpf

Trying to add a corner radius to the ListBox for my sidemenu navigation bar. So that that listboxitems dont spill onto the background.

Here is  my current style for my listbox and listboxitems.

```
    <Style x:Key="NavigationListBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Padding="0"
                    CornerRadius="5"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                  Focusable="false">
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

    <Style x:Key="NavigationListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="123"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="123"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SpecialButtonHighlightBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonClickBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And it looks like this. (the icons messed up due to something unrelated)

[image]

The listbox items corners are spilling onto the background behind the listbox.

Setting the CornerRadius property on the listboxitems to "5,5,0,0" gets the effect im wanting if the item is the first visible item in the listbox. However if it isnt the first item you can see the corners when i want it to be a square (second image)

[image]

[image]

I supose i could get the first(and last) visible item then set there corner radius to "5,5,0,0" and "0,0,5,5" respectively however that seems quite inelegant and a pain.

Really assumed setting the CornerRadius would work for this? no idea why it isnt.

Comment: I miunderstood your intention. To accomplish it, you need switch Style for ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle depending on wheter the item is the first or the last of the collection. You can accomlish the former by XAML but you need some code-behind for the latter.

Answer (score -1):

it answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175008/customize-the-border-property-with-cornerradius-for-listbox) like this

```
<ListBox ...>
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
<!--...-->
```